# Fetch array of url's

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working with redux and I am trying to fetch Star War API.

Here is my code:

```
import { MOVIES_ERROR, MOVIE_CHARACTERS } from "./types";

// Get all characters

export const getCharacters = (userId) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/films/${userId}`);
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error("sometheing went wrong");
    }
    const getData = await res.json();
    const characters = await getData.characters;
    let people = [];

    Promise.all(
      characters.map((url) =>
        fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((name) => people.push(name))
      )
    );
    dispatch({
      type: MOVIE_CHARACTERS,
      payload: people,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: MOVIES_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
    });
  }
};
```

when I make a console log inside a promise. all I got people array filled with all the data, but when I dispatch it I got an empty array in the reducer. can anyone tell me what the mistake that i did?

Comment: have you tried  .then((name) => people.push(name)).then(() =  dispatch({
      type: MOVIE_CHARACTERS,
      payload: people,
    }); 
basically, just add the dispatch to the promise

Comment: @tachko,  I tried this one and also work fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem just now, I need to add await before Promise.all :)